# Why is my call to "owner" in a "has_many" relationship not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 5.0.7.1, and I see in [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) that my CollectionProxy instance should have access to an "@owner" instance variable:

> Association proxies in Active Record are middlemen between the object
>   that holds the association, known as the @owner, and the actual
>   associated object, known as the @target. The kind of association any
>   proxy is about is available in @reflection. That's an instance of the
>   class ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection.
>
> the association proxy in blog.posts has the object in blog as @owner,
>   the collection of its posts as @target, and the @reflection object
>   represents a :has_many macro.
>
> This class delegates unknown methods to @target via method_missing.

In my Rails app, I've got the following (rather unrealistic) test code:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments  do
    def number_five
      if owner.is_a? Post
        Comment.where(id: 5, post_id: self.id)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

When I call `Post.last.commments.number_five`, I get the following error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `owner' for #
<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fcbb9106120>)
```

When I add `byebug` to the line in between `def number_five` and `owner.is_a? Post`, and I check the value of `self`, I see it's `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, so I *think* I'm calling `owner` in a scope where it should be defined.

I've tried `Post.last.comments.instance_variables`, and I don't see `:@owner`, only the following:

```
[:@association, :@klass, :@table, :@values, :@offsets, 
:@loaded, :@predicate_builder, :@scope]
```

I've also tried the following:

```
comments = Post.last.comments
def comments.get_owner
  self.owner
end
```

This returns the same `NameError` as above.

For what it's worth, when I run `Post.last.comments.class`, I see it's `Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`.

Given how the docs read, I'd expect to be able to call either `Post.last.comments.owner` or `@owner` from within `Post.last.comments` (both of which I've tried), and have it return the value of `Post.last`.  Is my expectation incorrect, or is my code wrong, or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is a little confusing. I remember having to spend a few hours guessing, reading the Rails source, and experimenting to figure this out the first time I need to get outside the association from an extension method.

`owner` is what you're after but that's a method on the association and you get the association via `proxy_association` (which is just an accessor method for `@association`):

```
has_many :comments  do
  def number_five
    if proxy_association.owner.is_a? Post
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the "right" or "official" way to do this but this is what I've been doing since Rails 4.

Comment: Confirmed the above code works.  If there's a more canonical, official way to do this then I'm all ears, otherwise I'm accepting this as an answer.  In the meantime, I may attempt a PR on the Rails docs specifying that `owner` is an attr on `@association`, not on `CollectionProxy`.  Then the core team could either confirm this is the "best" way or suggest a better way.

Comment: I'd be interested in the result of such a PR.

Comment: Issue report here- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34829.  Any feedback on the wording or clarity of the issue would be appreciated.  Will follow up with a PR if the core team agrees with the change.